# Java Futures "do the easy/fast ones first" or "speed of Execution Priority Queue"

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

I took a look at ExecutorCompletionService, but that wasn't *quite* it.

I've got a Collection of Runnables.   Some are going to complete very quickly, while others are going to take hours.  I'd like to get the fast ones done first, but I don't know ahead of time which ones the fast ones are.  So... I think that means "try all of them with a 1 second timeout.  Then increase to a 2x timeout.  Keep 2x-ing the timeout until done."

Is there a library or structure that handles this sort of thing?  I can't execute them all at once with an unbounded ExecutorService because I'll run out of memory.

Comment: That sounds like a *great* way to waste huge amounts of time. What sort of jobs are these?

Comment: Using reflection to compare all possible sorting algorithms in a library

Comment: A timeout is impossible unless your Runnables properly handle interrupts.

Comment: All I need is a thread yield somewhere in the loop, true?

Comment: 'Handle interrupts' means that the code uses checking of the interrupt flag and propagation of interruptedexceptions to respond to interruption, so that it does its cleanup and is terminated. Thread.yield isn't good for much of anything

Comment: No easy way to kill a thread that is refusing to die?